# HTML5 Boilerplate + Twitter Bootstrap: print style issue

Tags: css, html5boilerplate

I did here a **HTML5 Boilerplate + Twitter Bootstrap** integration, just calling the bootstrap.css and HTML5BP style.css (in that order).

So far, so good, but I have a issue here: in the Boilerplate stylesheet, in the print section, the rules I put there are ineffectives... For example:

```css
@media print {
    aside { display:none; }
}
```

When I preview the print, the dawn `aside` still in there... I'm not sure if this is a HTML5BP+TB combo issue or only with the HTML5BP; anyway, I'll thank some help with this!

Regards!

Comment: Try
    @media print {
        aside { display:none!important; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the print stylesheets you put in .less files are ignored, if you use less.js to compile the css on page load. Try compiling your files with [recess](https://github.com/twitter/recess) or lessc.

Comment: So did that work @TárcioZemel? I was using in-browser compilation with less.js which didn't work with print styles. Recess or lessc however seemed to have handled it properly.